# C# loop gets faster after some runs

Tags: c#, .net, loops, .net-core, while-loop

I wrote the following while loop:

```
while (true)
{
    //check number of execution
    if (_executionCountLog == 10)
        break;

    //another Loop
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //Doing something...
    }

    //Save Time Log in a List collection.
    _timeLog.Add(DateTime.Now);

    //Count the number of execution.
    _executionCountLog++;
}
```

the result of Time Lapsed is as follows:

[image: Execution Time Log]

The first run took about 14ms, the second run about 4ms, the third about 2ms and the rest of them took less than 1ms.

Q1: Why is that?

Q2: And also what to do so all runs take less than 1ms?

Comment: to q1: might depend _extensively_ on what `//Doing something...` is, as well as the JIT. to q2: throw more hardware at the problem. also: you get more precise measurements with the stopwatch-class

Comment: One possibility is the microprocessor has cache memory which is very fast memory but take time to load the memory.  So initially the slow time is the loading of the cache.

Comment: If you want to benchmark your code, consider using an *appropriate* tool for that. Your benchmarking is wrong. A good tool for that is e.g. [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).